# Not sure what two PNPs are doing

Tags: transistors, pnp

I've been delving into analog a bit more and am a little confused by a configuration I saw of two PNP BJTs.

I saw two emitters tied together and then their collectors tied together through a resistor. Their bases had different drives. What does this configuration accomplish.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6jfTf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT: I'm not 100%, but I believe in the circuit that I have found the inputs. Apologies if it looks vague. I'm attempting to keep the question simple.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCVbTZ.png)</sup>

Comment: Most people would be confused by this circuit. I do not know what it is for. If I put something like that in a schematic, I would add a note explaining what it is supposed to do. Just trying to validate your confusion.

Comment: It seems like some kind of comparator circuit to me.

Comment: Can you add some details explaining where you saw this circuit? A book? You reverse engineered a PCB? Photo / link? Put the info **in the question**.

Comment: Is it a badly drawn long-tailed pair? With missing emitter load?

Comment: I think I agree with @EJP- the circuit looks incomplete.  Is it from a schematic, or was it recreated from an existing PCB tracing the circuit?

Answer (score 2):

If there are no other power supply connections, then they might be some sort of protection circuit, using the back-to-back BE junctions as crude zener diodes.

Answer (score 0):

From the question I am assuming that you are decoding an existing PCB, which means some elements may be missing.

This looks a lot like a schmitt trigger, designed to threshold an analog signal into a binary one.

The full design and explanation can be seen on
http://www.johnhearfield.com/Eng/Schmitt.htm
under the **A simpler alternative** heading towards the bottom.
[image: Schmitt Trigger]